How to set custom vite config settings in Angular 18?
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular18",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "less",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.less"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          ...
}


I want to use module federation through Vite, but I don't know how to customise some Vite configurations in the same way as using @angular-builders/custom-webpack.
Is there a package similar to @angular-builders/custom-webpack like @angular-builders/custom-vite?
Or there are other ways to customise the Vite configuration?

Module federation as of Webpack module federation will not work in Vite. Anyway, asking for packages recommendations is off-topic.

@JSONDerulo  Vite has plugins for the Federation module: @originjs/vite-plugin-federation

Strange naming decision, they implement something similar to module federation and name it exactly the same. I can see how this can be confusing. Maybe you can check out native federation.

@JSONDerulo My question focuses on how to customise the Vite configuration rather than the module federation, as there may be other requirements for customising the Vite configuration
